# Ubuntu 18.04 Suspends only after lock

Tags: suspend, power-management, lock, lid

it looks like my installation of Ubuntu is having some issues with the order of operations. Whenever I try to suspend the system using the `systemctl suspend` command or by closing the lid after configuring the "suspend on lid close" setting in gnome-tweaks, the OS locks, turns off the screen, and only suspends after I enter my credentials.

Due to some other issues between my touchpad, USB and wifi adapter, I have a script in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` to turn those devices off to allow for a proper suspend.

Currently I have it set up using acpi to execute a script on lid close and use `pm-suspend` which works but is not ideal as that forgoes any locking whatsoever and no password is required on resume.

Bellow is my acpi script `/etc/acpi/lid.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

grep -q close /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
   /lib/systemd/system-sleep/sleep.sh "pre"
   pm-suspend
else
   /lib/systemd/system-sleep/sleep.sh "post"
fi
```

This is my `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/sleep.sh` script to manage my devices:

```
#!/bin/sh 

if [ "${1}" = "pre" ]; then

  #Turn off wifi.
  nmcli radio wifi off

  state=`cat /proc/acpi/wakeup | grep 'XHC' | cut -f3 | cut -d' ' -f1 | tr -d '*'`
  if [ "$state" = "enabled" ]
   then
   echo "XHC" > /proc/acpi/wakeup
  fi

elif [ "${1}" = "post" ]; then

  #restart psmouse driver to fix two finger scroll.
  modprobe -r psmouse
  modprobe psmouse

  #Turn on wifi.
  nmcli radio wifi on

  #Enable XHC USB Chip.
  state=`cat /proc/acpi/wakeup | grep 'XHC' | cut -f3 | cut -d' ' -f1 | tr -d '*'`
  if [ "$state" = "disabled" ]
   then
   echo "XHC" > /proc/acpi/wakeup
  fi
fi
```

Any help getting everything to run smoothly would be appreciated!

Comment: Out of curiosity I updated to 19.10 to see if the issue persists. It does. Strangely enough the power button suspends properly but closing the lid does not.